# How can i put a string in one line

Tags: java, string, hex, ascii

i'm doing some conversion, from Hex to Ascii, when i convert the string, i got the following example:

> F23C040100C1
>
> 100D200000000000
>
> 0000

I know that the string is coming like this, because of the base 16, but i want too put it in just one line, like this:

> F23C040100C1100D2000000000000000

How can i do that?

I have tried:

```
mensagem.replaceAll("\r\n", " ");
```

Comment: Show the code generating the string... For one thing you could try escaping the \\, use `mensagem.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems you could be running into, so I'll cover all them in this answer.

First, any methods on `String` which appear to modify it actually return a new instance of `String`. That means if you do this:

```
String something = "Hello";
something.replaceAll("l", "");
System.out.println(something); //"Hello"
```

You'll want to do

```
something = something.replaceAll("l", "");
```

Or in your case

```
mensagem = mensagem.replaceAll("\r\n", " ");
```

Secondly, there might not be any `\r` in the newline, but there is a `\n`, or vice versa. Because of that, you want to say that

> if `\r` exists, remove it. if `\n` exists, also remove it

You can do so like this:

```
mensagem = mensagem.replaceAll("\r*\n*", " ");
```

The `*` operator in a regular expression says to match zero or more of the preceding symbol.

Comment: Lol, I was going to say pretty much the same thing. You beat me

Comment: Accept this answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

```
mensagem.replaceAll("\r\n|\r|\n", "");
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.